# Mostrar sólo dos números después de la coma, sin redondear

Tags: c++, double, redondeo

Tengo una duda respecto al uso de *precision* de `<iomanip>`, necesito mostrar sólo dos decimales después de la coma en una variable de tipo `double`, pero al usarlo de la siguiente manera *(adjunto bloque de código)* me entrega los dos números después de la coma redondeados:

```
if(func=="show"){
  for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
    x+=nums[i];
  }
  x=x/nums.size();
  cout.precision(2);
  cout << fixed;
  cout << x << endl;
}
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para mostrarlos sin redondear? *(Quiero evitar el uso de la multiplicación y el truncado de número)*.

Comment: ¿Puedes ponernos un ejemplo de los datos que tienes como entrada y lo que recibes como salida?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes forzar redondeos a la baja con `std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);`, que pertenece a la cabecera [`<cfenv>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cfenv):

El siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cfenv>

int main()
{
    float test[] {
        1.000,
        1.001,
        1.002,
        1.003,
        1.004,
        1.005,
        1.006,
        1.007,
        1.008,
        1.009,
        1.010,
    };

    std::cout.precision(2);
    std::cout << std::fixed;

    for (const auto &v : test) std::cout << v << '\t';
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    for (const auto &v : test) std::cout << v << '\t';

    return 0;
}
```

Muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 1.00  1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.01    1.01    1.01    1.01    1.01    
> 1.00  1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00
> ```

Observa que el comportamiento por defecto es hacer redondeo científico, pero con `FE_DOWNWARD` le dices que quieres que todos los redondeos sean a la baja.